# Maven pom to generate classfiles for another pom

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project that depends on generated sources.  These sources need to be generated by a java program built by another maven pom.  (In this case the sources are generated by the greendao source generator, but they could be generated by any generic java executable.)

I haven't dealt with this sort of interdependency between maven projects before.  Assuming I want to use a reactor to build these two submodules, how can I ensure that the first module is built AND executed and generates its source files to be included in the second module?

Comment: You have module A which generates classes by greendao. You install/deploy it and you include it to B project as dependency. Could you confirm?

Comment: Close.  I have module A which builds the greendao class generator when I install/deploy it.  Then I run the generator from module A to generate the source for module B.  Module B consists of those generated sources and only those generated sources.

Comment: Do you have something similar to [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)? It generates from wsdl source files and include it as sources to `<sourceRoot>` folder. If yes you can use module A as maven plugin (of course you need to write necessary classes). Or second solution is to run it in phase generate-sources. You can use [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to include new source folders to project. I prefer to generate sources in other maven module and include it as dependencies.

Comment: I'm not using any sort of plugin.  Module A generates a java executable, and running that executable generates the sources for module B.

Answer (score 0):

Module A generates sources.  Module B depends on Module A.  If you say that Module B depends on Module A in Module B's pom, I think the reactor will figure out it needs to build Module A first.

Comment: Sure, that's part of the problem.  But how do I tell Module A the destination directory in Module B to generate the files to?  There doesn't seem to be a good way to do that.

Comment: If Module A generates the sources, Module B should get the sources when Module B depends on Module A.  How/Why are you designing it otherwise?

Comment: How? Sources, not class files